# Dataframe of the Top X Values of the Top Y Days - Pandas Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data about three variables where I want to find the largest X values of one variable on a per day basis. Previously I wrote some code to find the hour where the max value of the day occurred, but now I want to add some options to find more max hours per day.

I've been able to find the Top X values per day for all the days, but I've gotten stuck on narrowing it down to the Top X Values from the Top X Days. I've included pictures detailing what the end result would hopefully look like.

**Data**
[image: data]

**Identified Top 2 Hours**
[image: Top2AllDays]

**Code**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'ID':['ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1','ID_1'],
'Year':[2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018],
'Month':[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6],
'Day':[12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,17,17,17,17],
'Hour':[19,20,21,22,11,12,13,19,19,20,21,22,18,19,20,21,19,20,21,23,19,20,21,22],
'var_1': [0.83,0.97,0.69,0.73,0.66,0.68,0.78,0.82,1.05,1.05,1.08,0.88,0.96,0.81,0.71,0.88,1.08,1.02,0.88,0.79,0.91,0.91,0.80,0.96],
'var_2': [47.90,42.85,67.37,57.18,66.13,59.96,52.63,54.75,32.54,36.58,36.99,37.23,46.94,52.80,68.79,50.84,37.79,43.54,48.04,38.01,42.22,47.13,50.96,44.19],
'var_3': [99.02,98.10,98.99,99.12,98.78,98.90,99.09,99.20,99.22,99.11,99.18,99.24,99.00,98.90,98.87,99.07,99.06,98.86,98.92,99.32,98.93,98.97,98.99,99.21],})

# Get the top 2 var2 values each day
top_two_var2_each_day = df.groupby(['ID', 'Year', 'Month',  'Day'])['var_2'].nlargest(2)
top_two_var2_each_day = top_two_var2_each_day.reset_index()

# set level_4 index to the current index
top_two_var2_each_day = top_two_var2_each_day.set_index('level_4')

# use the index from the top_two_var2 to get the rows from df to get values of the other variables when top 2 values occured
top_2_all_vars = df[df.index.isin(top_two_var2_each_day.index)]
```

**End Goal Result**

I figure the best way would be to average the two hours to identify what days have the largest average, then go back into *top_2_all_vars* dataframe and grab the rows where the Days occur. I am unsure how to proceed.

```
mean_day = top_2_all_vars.groupby(['ID', 'Year', 'Month',  'Day'],as_index=False)['var_2'].mean()
top_2_day = mean_day.nlargest(2, 'var_2')
```

[image]

**Final Dataframe**
[image]

This is the result I am trying to find. A dataframe consisting of the Top 2 values of var_2 from each of the Top 2 days.

*Code I previously used to find the single largest value of each day, but I don't know how I would make it work for more than a single max per day*

```
# For each ID and Day, Find the Hour where the Max Amount of var_2 occurred and save the index location
df_idx = df.groupby(['ID', 'Year', 'Month',  'Day',])['var_2'].transform(max) == df['var_2']

# Now the hour has been found, store the rows in a new dataframe based on the saved index location
top_var2_hour_of_each_day = df[df_idx]
```

Using Groupbys may be not the best way to go about it, but I am open to anything.

Comment: To be honest, I'm really confused about exactly what your looking for. Is it just the max of the 3 var's on each day?? If so then ```df.groupby(['Month','Day']).agg({'var_1':'max', 'var_2':'max', 'var_3':'max'})``` will work.

Comment: @BenPap Basically three steps. 1.) Find the top 2 values of var_2 per day. 2.) Find the Top 2 Days based off the mean value of var_2 of Step#1. 3.) Create a new dataframe from df that shows the top two hours of each of the top 2 days.

Comment: Is your data only in June? or does it span  multiple months as well?

Comment: On occasion it will be multiple months, but this time it is just June.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach:

If your data spans multiple months its a lot harder dealing with it when the month and day are in different columns. So First I made a new column called 'Date' which just combines the month and the day.

```
df['Date'] = df['Month'].astype('str')+"-"+df['Day'].astype('str')
```

Next we need the top two values of var_2 per day, and then average them. So we can create a really simple function to find exactly that.

```
def topTwoMean(series):
    top = series.sort_values(ascending = False).iloc[0]
    second = series.sort_values(ascending = False).iloc[1]
    return (top+second)/2
```

We then use our function, sort by the average of var_2 to get the highest 2 days, then save the dates to a list.

```
maxDates = df.groupby('Date').agg({'var_2': [topTwoMean]})\
             .sort_values(by = ('var_2', 'topTwoMean'), ascending = False)\
             .reset_index()['Date']\
             .head(2)\
             .to_list()
```

Finally we filter by the dates chosen above, then find the highest two of var_2 on those days.

```
df[df['Date'].isin(maxDates)]\
             .groupby('Date')\
             .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('var_2', ascending = False).head(2))\
             .reset_index(drop = True)


        ID  Year    Month   Day Hour    var_1   var_2   var_3   Date

0      ID_1 2018     6      12   21     0.69    67.37   98.99   6-12
1      ID_1 2018     6      12   22     0.73    57.18   99.12   6-12
2      ID_1 2018     6      13   11     0.66    66.13   98.78   6-13
3      ID_1 2018     6      13   12     0.68    59.96   98.90   6-13
```